# How to get values passed via GET with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Say I have the following, and that I got the IDs dynamically.

```
<div class="search_results">
<p>user 1 <a href="phpfile.php?id=3">Add</a></p>
<p>user 1 <a href="phpfile.php?id=4">Add</a></p>
</div>
```

If I didn't use ajax, I could catch the passed values in `phpfile.php` with `$_GET['id']`,
but how can I use that with jquery?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'phpfile.php', // how to add those values here?
    success: function(data) {
        // do smth
    }
});
```

Comment: And how are you calling ajax with hyperlink?

Comment: I'm not, im just explaining what I want to achieve.

Comment: Where is your id going to come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the data parameter:

```
url: 'phpfile.php',
data: {id: 3}
```

If you have to take the id from the HTML as displayed:

```
$('.search_results a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'phpfile.php',
    data: {id: $(this).attr('href').match(/id=(\d*)/)[1]},
    success: function (data) {
        // do something
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `data:` and an object, rather than concatenating `?data=3` to the URL.

Comment: But i don't know what the id is, I hardcoded just to demonstrate.

Comment: then you need to replace the hardcoded 3 on my code by the id. If you get the id from Javascript: {id: idVar}, if from PHP: {id: <?php echo idVar ?>

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

To facilitate getting the ID easier, put it into a separate attribute so that it can be read directly by JavaScript/jQuery. If this is impossible, then keep your URI the way it is in the `href`.

```
<div class="search_results">
    <p>user 3 <a href="phpfile.php" data-user-id="3">Add</a></p>
    <p>user 4 <a href="phpfile.php" data-user-id="4">Add</a></p>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

Here, I'm using the `data` property of the jQuery ajax object to send the `id` parameter. As you can see, the value is grabbed from the `data-user-id` attribute of the HTML element.

`e.preventDefault()` is to prevent the browser's default action of following the link to the target `href`.

```
$('a[data-user-id]').click(function (e) {
    'use strict';

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $(this).prop('href'),
        data: {
            id: $(this).attr('data-user-id')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you may use a `button` element.

Answer (score 0):

`url: 'phpfile.php', 
data: data,`

Just retrieve the values from data at your server side code

You can use the below line to get all the data from your form into ajax

`var data = $('form').serialize();`

The above method can be applied only if you are passing data using html form

Comment: I don't see a `form` being used anywhere here.

Comment: Yes just gave an example with form

Comment: I meant that there is no `<form>` anywhere in the HTML.

Comment: I guess Ollicca just wanted to know how to pass data into ajax. That's what I showed in my example using form submit method

Comment: Updated the answer for a better understanding